# How can I get the specific string from a SQL row and perform further ETL on the extracted string?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am learning PL/SQL and struck at a problem statement where the result required is a specific string from `select` statement which is stored as row value in a table.

Example

`select distinct ID from emp, order where emp.ID = order.ID and (emp.type = 1 or emp.type = 100010 )`

The above mentioned `select` statement is stored as a row entity in `Table3` .

Problem Statement :

1. The Requirement is to extract both `1` and `100010` and store them in a character variable to get the English Description of `1` and `100010` from `Table4`

Can anyone help me in writing the RegX or suggest me some different approach for the problem statement.

Note : Their are multiple `table2.column3`  in a single SQL statement and the max length for ID is `6` and the minimum is `1`

Edits : Updated the Example Statement

Comment: MySQL does not support PL/SQL. Check your DBMS carefully. *Example* Errorneous, will produce "ambiguous column name" error.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am working on PL/SQL block and I was able to extract the data from DB. the above-mentioned problem statement is a ` check ` to ensure the row's which are being selected is fulfilling the requirement.

Comment: 19c enterprise edition

Comment: :facepalm: This is OracleDB, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much a *dummy* example. If table and column names aren't really `table1` or `column2` but something more meaningful (and don't contain any numbers), then that's rather simple:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'select distinct ID from emp, order where emp.ID = order.ID and (emp.type = 1 or order.code = 100010 )' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) first_number,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) second_number
  5  from test;

FIRST_NUMBER    SECOND_NUMBER
--------------- ---------------
1               100010

SQL>
```

If, on the other hand, table or column names really have numbers, then it isn't that simple.

Comment: Thank you for the response and apologies for using the incorrect example

Comment: If I understand correctly ` \d+` is extracting the numeric digits used in the select statement. 
if their are other conditions attached like ` emp.city_id = 100 ` and i just want the ` emp.type ` ID will that work here ?

Comment: It depends on its position. For example, "regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, **2**)" scans the string, searches for digits, starting from position 1, looking for the **2nd** occurrence.

Comment: got it, but the their are multiple statements which are clubbed with in INTERSECT and UNION operators so it gonna be little complex to get the value's as per their positions can you suggest a bit dynamic approach ?

Comment: Exactly, it's going to be **complex**. You'll have to develop set of rules to successfully parse those strings. Pure SQL solution might not even work, so you'll have to move on to PL/SQL (i.e. a stored procedure, if not the whole package).

Comment: Hi, i was able to get the string using regexp_substr() and level by statement. It's picking up the emp.type = 1 and all similar conditions but i it's also creating empty rows as well. any suggestion to remove the empty rows ?

Comment: You'll need to include a WHERE clause as it **filters** rows that are returned.